# VBA Excel - Unable to open existing Word Document file

Tags: vba, excel, macros, ms-word

I have a simple macro that opens a Word Document using Excel. I made sure the Word Object Library is properly referenced but when running this macro it freezes after Documents.Open is called (based on me seeing where it fails in the debugger). I don't know if it is a OLE Automation Error but the macro freezes and I have to force close Excel.

```
Public Const Dir = "C:/Temp/"
Public Const File = "temp.docx"

Public Sub OpenFile()

Dim f As String: f = Dir & File

Dim oWord As Object, oDoc As Object
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(f)
oDoc.Visible = True

End Sub
```

I get this message as well: (even though there is no other application open)

[image]

Is there an alternative to opening a file with Excel and how I rewrite my program?

Comment: Have  you tried changing your Dir variable - that's a reserved name - and you're probably getting a Word error you can't see when you try to open that "file". You should also change your "File" variable name too - that can be a reserved word too depending on references you've set

Comment: Also, prefix instead, such as `pthWordLocation` and `flnmWordTemplate`, stops the risk of using reserved words, if you've the library referenced, then use `dim wdApp as word.application` and `dim wdDocument as word.document`

Comment: @dbmitch That surprisingly worked.... I have no idea how you came to that conclusion. Make it an answer please

Comment: OT: If you are using late binding, why to add the reference for word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested - this is a common problem

You should change your `Dir` variable - that's a reserved name - and you're probably getting a Word error you can't see when you try to open that "file".

You should also change your `File` variable name too - that can be a reserved word too depending on references you've set

> **Added Comment:**

With regard to it freezing - you can remove the `oDoc.Visible = True` statement and replace it with `oWord.Visible = True` *BEFORE* the problem statement `Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(f)`. That would popup the error indicating you had a problem with your filename

Comment: OT: Shouldn't be this closed since it may be considered as a typo using restricted name variables?

Comment: @Sgdva -  Where did you find that reason to close? You're welcome to flag question as duplicate or whatever reason for closing, but typos are a common question on this site. I don't believe I've ever seen one closed for that reason. Illuminate me.

Comment: Quote: On [2. ...Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error...](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Don't worry, I just learned that today as well.

Comment: Nice - never knew that - but IMHO this one still doesn't fit that issue. restricted name variables often don't show up as typos and an app hanging because it wasn't visible yet is more of a troublseshooting tip.

Comment: We are taking so much OT in this thread, there is a [meta thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212024/dealing-with-questions-with-obvious-replies) about it. OT(ha): I didn't vote to close neither down voted but, recently I faced a similar situation and got vote downed for answering referring to the link provided.

Comment: Wowza - must have got someone on a bad day at the office